# Outlook AdvancedSearch DASL using c#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, mailitem

I am doing advancesearch in outlook using c# office addin (VSTO)

**Filter DASL query** -  urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > 'dd.M.yy HH:mm'  - Returning Items in my Machine. But it is not working in some other machines .
My machine date time format is dd-mm-yy

Filter urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived > 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' - Not returing items in my machine and working in some other machine .

Is there any universal format is there to filter to work in all machines(environments).

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are passing by hand the format.
From [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841(v=office.12).aspx). (emphasis mine)

> **The format used by Outlook corresponds to the General (short date and**
>   **short time) pattern** in the DateTimeFormatInfo class. If you use the
>   Parse method of the DateTime structure, you should be certain that the
>   argument to the Parse method follows the short date and short time
>   format for the current locale. If you use the constructor for the
>   DateTime structure, you need to specify year, month, day, hour,
>   minute, and second arguments and then **use the ToString method with the
>   "g" format specifier to convert the date-time value to the short date
>   and short time string expected by Outlook.** The date specifier argument
>   to the ToString method is case-sensitive, so be sure to use "g" as the
>   format specifier. When you use the DateTime constructor and the "g"
>   format specifier in the ToString method, you create a date-time
>   literal that will be interpreted correctly by Outlook.

I would create the filters like in the link, creating a `DateTime` object and then converting it to string using the `"g"` parameter. From the documentation:

```
string searchCriteria = String.Format("\"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived\" >= '{0}'", new DateTime(2005, 6, 12, 15, 30, 0).ToString("g"))
```

That way you can be sure the date will be properly formatted according to the culture of the system the query is running on.

Note: Remember it is Case sensitive so you must use **"g"** and not **"G"**.

Comment: In AdvanceSearch we cannot use JET query format it will thrown error.We have to  use DASL query format. It is string filter = "[LastModificationTime] < '" + 
    new DateTime(2005, 6, 12, 15, 30, 0).ToString("g") + "'"; JET format .

Comment: @Aishwarya, sorry about the format, I updated the example, did you try something like the code I updated?